# Slack autoformats messages when using markdown styling while typing

Tags: slack

When using backticks in Slack, ie, `like this`, Slack automatically updates the formatting as you type. This makes it difficult to do such things like:

```
Put punctuation after an `inline code snippet`, like this.
```

````
```typescript
// denote the desired syntax for slack to use while
// parsing your code snippet
const noop = () => {};
```
````

Is there any way to disable this automatic formatting feature? I am a vim user and I do not like when text editors consume symbols and format my text on my behalf as I am trying to write.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods:

- Change `Preferences > Advanced > Format Messages with Markup` to off
- You can do `Cmd + Z` to negate the formatting and continue typing the message as normal.